# Segmentation fault caused by memcpy despite counting every bit

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am trying to copy data from an array of characters into a member of my class using memcpy. I set a breakpoint in the debugger write before memcpy. I checked all of the variables that I will be using and the i calculated how much space is left in the destination and it looks like it should work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <cstring>

class bigNum
{
    unsigned int dataLength;
    unsigned long long int *data;

    public:
        bigNum(){
            //long long int is 8 bytes so (2 * 1024)long long int = 16 KiB
            //  if that's not enough, we can always add more later
            dataLength = 2048;
            data = new unsigned long long [dataLength];
        };

        virtual ~bigNum(){delete[] data;};

        //bigNum& operator=(const bigNum& other);

        bigNum& set(char chars[], unsigned int charsLength) {
            //calculate where we will start writing the data
            void *writeStart = (void*)(
                (unsigned long long)data + dataLength*64 - charsLength*8
            );

            //DEBUG -- set a couple of the array elements to watch in debugger
            data[2047] = data[2046] = ~((unsigned long long)0);

            //zero out the space before writeStart
            std::memset(data, 0, dataLength*8 - charsLength);

            //write the data starting at writeStart
            std::memcpy(writeStart, chars, charsLength);

            return *this;
        }
};


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bigNum myNum;
    char chars[9] = {'a'};

    myNum.set(chars, 9);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Individual bits are not addressable, the minimal addressable unit is a byte. Writestart calculation is wrong. Also there are a few issues with the style if you care to listen.

Comment: `memset` and `memcpy` are very rarely, if ever, necessary in modern c++. `new unsigned long long [dataLength]{}` will zero the array, and `std::copy` can copy it for you. Or you could just use `vector`s and forget about legacy c code entirely.

Comment: Modern C++ style would also have given you a working copy ctor. The current copy ctor will cause a crash (double delection of `data` )

Comment: @Nick, the pointer counts the number of bytes? So if I add one to it, it will point to the next byte?

Comment: I need to specifically zero out the array because it will be set more than once. Also, there is no copy constructor defined yet.

Comment: Vectors won't work for me in this case. I will have a lot of these classes and I will need to read and write data a lot. It needs to be fixed size.

Comment: @Person93 If it needs to be fixed size then why don't you just use `unsigned long long int data[2048];` or `std::array<unsigned long long int, 2048> data;`?

Comment: I declare the array by writing unsigned long long [dataLength]. I used a variable rather than hard coding the number so that if I decide to change it later, I only need to change it in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is in this statement here:

```
        void *writeStart = (void*)(
            (unsigned long long)data + dataLength*64 - charsLength*8
        );
```

That is, it appears you're trying to get the right write location in *bits*, when you should be doing this in *bytes*.

When you have statements like `dataLength*64` and `charsLength*8`, you're multiplying by their sizes in *bits*, when what you're dealing with - pointers - refers to *bytes*.

But still, it seems you're playing loose with integer sizes. *Don't do that!* It means your code will break on other machine architectures. Instead of assuming that `unsigned long long` is 64 bits, find out exactly how many bytes they are using `sizeof(unsigned long long)`, or if you want a fixed width integer, use the corresponding type like `uint64_t`.

Then again, with C++, you should stick to standard containers like `std::vector`.

Comment: Thanks! I will make these changes when I get back to my computer.